# Unexpected token "end of expression" of value "" around position 1

Tags: php, expression, symfony

I never had this kind of error before, and I don't know what to search and where to begin.

I created a function in a CRUD with Symfony 3, and when I get to the route, I get the following error (with its trace) :

> Unexpected token "end of expression" of value "" around position 1.
>   500 Internal Server Error - SyntaxError

```
    } elseif ($token->test(Token::PUNCTUATION_TYPE, '{')) {
        $node = $this->parseHashExpression();
    } else {
        throw new SyntaxError(sprintf('Unexpected token "%s" of value "%s"', $token->type, $token->value), $token->cursor);
    }
}
```

So I thought this was a problem of brackets, but PHPStorms counts 19 opening AND closing brackets (these one "{") and 112 opening AND closing parenthesis.

I don't really know what to show you, so here is the full content of the functions I added before getting the error:

**Public function**

```
/**
     * @Route("/{id}/encours", name="mission_encours")
     * @Security has_role('ROLE_RECRUTEUR')
     * @Method("POST")
     */
    public function enCoursAction(Request $request, Mission $mission){
        $form = $this->missionInProgress($mission);
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()){
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $mission->setStatut("En cours");
            $em->persist($mission);
            $em->flush();
        }
        return $this->redirectToRoute('mission_index');
    }
```

**private function**

```
/**
     * @param Mission $mission
     * @Security has_role('ROLE_RECRUTEUR')
     * @return \Symfony\Component\Form\Form The form
     */
    private function missionInProgress(Mission $mission){
        return $this->createFormBuilder()
            ->setAction($this->generateUrl('mission_encours', array('id' => $mission->getId())))
            ->setMethod('POST')
            ->getForm()
        ;
    }
```

These functions goal are to change a mission's status by clicking on a submit button inside the "show" view of the CRUD. The user gets redirected, the status changes, then the user goes back to the mission list.

Even though, I don't know what could be wrong, I work with PHPStorm and tells me nothing about missing brackets.

Does anyone ever had this problem and knows how to resolve it ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

In security annotation  are missing sights (" "). 

Change from
@Security has_role('ROLE_RECRUTEUR')

To
@Security("has_role('ROLE_RECRUTEUR')")